# Using multiple functions with 4 parameters each so that they may display the maximum, average, and minimum

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JavaScript and wanted to ask the following question: I was trying to use a main function to prompt the user to input 4 numbers, then pass those through the display function. The display function then takes those and passes them through max, min, avg and prints them on the screen. Is there a reason why my code doesn't work? (have been looking online for days now and no matter what I do I can't seem to make it work)

Here is the code: [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/s8je6kxu/4/) (Has comments)

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
The main() function first reads 4 numbers from the user with proper prompt; then it calls the display() function with four numbers

Trying to find the max, avg, and min using multiple functions with 4 parameters each    
-->
```

.

```
<html>
<body onload="main()">

<p id="max"></p>
<p id="avg"></p>
<p id="min"></p>


<!-- JS begins here-->

<script>
function main()
{
alert("Please enter 4 numbers so that I may give you the maximum, minimum, and the average of the 4 numbers.");

 var n1 = +prompt("Please enter the first number: ");
 var n2 = +prompt("Please enter the Second number: ");
 var n3 = +prompt("Please enter the Third number: ");
 var n4 = +prompt("Please enter the Fourth number: ");
}

function display(n1, n2, n3, n4)    
{
document.getElementById("max").innerHTML = "The maximum is: " + max1();
document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = "The average is: " + avg1();
document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = "the minimum us: " + min1();
    alert(max1());
}

function max1(n1, n2, n3, n4)
{
 if(n1 > n2 && n1 > n3 && n1 > n4)
    {
        return n1;
    }
 else if(n2 > n1 && n2 > n3 && n2 > n4)
     {
         return n2;
     }
 else if(n3 > n2 && n3 > n1 && n3 > n4)
     {
         return n3;
     }
 else if(n4 > n2 && n4 > n3 && n4 > n1)
     {
         return n4;
     }
}

function avg1(n1, n2, n3, n4)
{
 var total = 4;
 avg = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4;
 return avg;
}

function min1(n1, n2, n3, n4)
{
 if(n1 < n2 && n1 < n3 && n1 < n4)
    {
        return = n1;
    }
 else if(n2 < n1 && n2 < n3 && n2 < n4)
     {
         return = n2;
     }
 else if(n3 < n2 && n3 < n1 && n3 < n4)
     {
         return = n3;
     }
 else if(n4 < n2 && n4 < n3 && n4 < n1)
     {
         return = n4;
     }
}

//max1();
//min1();
//avg1();


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey =D I recommend using an array for this, rather than passing in separate variables. Would you like me to show you how to do it with an array?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm not quite at that level yet so I wanted to learn how to do it this way first. thank you though :D

Comment: Without using an array, that looks like the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Please specify more the question. What really happens? Does the prompt windows appear? All of them, or just the first? The results are shown, or they are wrong for some reason?

Comment: Btw, it looks like your main method is missing calling the display() in the end

Comment: It's supposed to go through each prompt and record the inputs to then pass those inputs through the other functions. Only thing that has worked was the Main() and the Display(). They are currently broken...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is here that you are writing the return with a = in your function `min1`. You are not using the total on your function `avg1` you can remove it and just remove this `=` and it would start working. You can create a value and add the value that you need to it and return it at the end

```
function max1(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
  if(n1 > n2 && n1 > n3 && n1 > n4) {
      return n1;
  }
  else if(n2 > n1 && n2 > n3 && n2 > n4) {
    return n2;
  }
  else if(n3 > n2 && n3 > n1 && n3 > n4) {
    return n3;
  }
  else if(n4 > n2 && n4 > n3 && n4 > n1) {
    return n4;
  }
}

function avg1(n1, n2, n3, n4)
{
  // you are not using this value 'total' you can remove it
 var total = 4;
 const avg = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4;
 return avg;
}

function min1(n1, n2, n3, n4)
{      
  let min = 0;
  if(n1 < n2 && n1 < n3 && n1 < n4) {
    min = n1;
  }
  else if(n2 < n1 && n2 < n3 && n2 < n4) {
   min = n2;
  }
  else if(n3 < n2 && n3 < n1 && n3 < n4) {
   min = n3;
  }
  else if(n4 < n2 && n4 < n3 && n4 < n1) {
   min = n4;
  }

  return min
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this code? We don't typically do codedumps here ^^

Comment: it is explained in the comments and it is the same code that is on the question.

Comment: @newbs - if you really aim to learn JavaScript, please take a look at `Math.max()` and `Math.min()`. There is no need to rewrite something that is already provided for us - it just wastes time. You can always find out what you can do here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference and use the search function at the top of the page. If you want to see how to use these please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `main()` executes, but nothing else happens. In `main` you need to call you display function `display(n1,n2,n3,n4)`.

But this still won't work. Take a close look at your function calls for `max1()`, `min1()` and `avg1()` -- note that you call them without any arguments, but you've declared the functions to require the four numbers as parameters.

**So instead of:**

`max1()`

**Do**

`max1(n1,n2,n3,n4)`

Etc.

Finally, you min and max functions are already part of JavaScript in the Math object.  So you don't even need them really. Just do:

`Math.max(n1,n2,n3,n4)` and that should give you the max integer. Do the same with `min1()` as `Math.min(n1,n2,n3,n4)` **assuming** integers are passed in, these should work fine.

**This is all you need**

```js
function main() {
  alert("Please enter 4 numbers so that I may give you the maximum, minimum, and the average of the 4 numbers."); //informs the user

  var n1 = +prompt("Please enter the first number: "); // asks user for number 1
  var n2 = +prompt("Please enter the Second number: "); // asks user for number 2
  var n3 = +prompt("Please enter the Third number: "); // asks user for number 3
  var n4 = +prompt("Please enter the Fourth number: "); // asks user for number 4
  display(n1, n2, n3, n4);
}

function display(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
  document.getElementById("max").innerHTML = "The maximum is: " + Math.max(n1, n2, n3, n4); //printing the maximum
  document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = "The average is: " + (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4; //printing the average
  document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = "the minimum is: " + Math.min(n1, n2, n3, n4); //prints minimum
  //alert(max1()); <--- maybe this would work better?
}
```

```html
<body onload="main()">

<div id="max"></div>
<div id="avg"></div>
<div id="min"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are missing calling display() after the 4th number input.
I prefer to declare var n1-n4 globally so you don't need them to pass down to functions so they can access it directly.

Here is the code:

```js
var n1 = 0;
  var n2 = 0;
  var n3 = 0;
  var n4 = 0;
  
  function main() {
  alert("Please enter 4 numbers so that I may give you the maximum, minimum, and the average of the 4 numbers."); //informs the user
    
     n1 = +prompt("Please enter the first number: "); // asks user for number 1
     n2 = +prompt("Please enter the Second number: ");// asks user for number 2
     n3 = +prompt("Please enter the Third number: ");// asks user for number 3
     n4 = +prompt("Please enter the Fourth number: ");// asks user for number 4
     
     display();
     }
 
 function display()    
    {
   document.getElementById("max").innerHTML = "The maximum is: " + max1(); //printing the maximum
     document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = "The average is: " + avg1(); //printing the average
  document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = "the minimum is: " + min1();//prints minimum
    //alert(max1()); <--- maybe this would work better?
    }
    
function max1() // function to find the max
    {
      if(n1 > n2 && n1 > n3 && n1 > n4)
       {
         return n1; //is return used correctly here?
       }
      else if(n2 > n1 && n2 > n3 && n2 > n4)
        {
          return n2;
        }
      else if(n3 > n2 && n3 > n1 && n3 > n4)
        {
          return n3;
        }
      else if(n4 > n2 && n4 > n3 && n4 > n1)
        {
          return n4;
        }
    }
    
function avg1() //function to find the average
    {
      var total = 4;
      avg = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4;
      return avg;
    }
    
 function min1() //function to find the minimum
    {
      if(n1 < n2 && n1 < n3 && n1 < n4)
       {
         return n1; //is return used correctly here?
       }
      else if(n2 < n1 && n2 < n3 && n2 < n4)
        {
          return n2;
        }
      else if(n3 < n2 && n3 < n1 && n3 < n4)
        {
          return n3;
        }
      else if(n4 < n2 && n4 < n3 && n4 < n1)
        {
          return n4;
        }
    }

//have seen examples where the following are used
    //max1();  
 //min1();
 //avg1();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--
The main() function first reads 4 numbers from the user with proper prompt; then it calls the display() function with four numbers

Trying to find the max, avg, and min using multiple functions with 4 parameters each 
-->


<html>
<body onload="main()">
    
    <p id="max"></p>
    <p id="avg"></p>
    <p id="min"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Please work on the syntax and call the display function. Code is below. It's self explanatory.*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Play With Numbers</title>
</head>
<body onload="main()">

    <p id="max"></p>
    <p id="avg"></p>
    <p id="min"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">     
    function main() {
        alert("Please enter 4 numbers so that I may give you the maximum, minimum, and the average of the 4 numbers."); //informs the user

         var n1 = +prompt("Please enter the first number: ");
         var n2 = +prompt("Please enter the Second number: ");
         var n3 = +prompt("Please enter the Third number: ");
         var n4 = +prompt("Please enter the Fourth number: ");
         display(n1, n2, n3, n4);
    }
    function display(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
        document.getElementById("max").innerHTML = "The maximum is: " + max1(n1, n2, n3, n4);
        document.getElementById("avg").innerHTML = "The average is: " + avg1(n1,n2, n3, n4);
        document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = "the minimum is: " + min1(n1, n2, n3, n4);
    }


    function max1(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
         if(n1 > n2 && n1 > n3 && n1 > n4)
            {
                return n1;
            }
         else if(n2 > n1 && n2 > n3 && n2 > n4)
             {
                 return n2;
             }
         else if(n3 > n2 && n3 > n1 && n3 > n4)
             {
                 return n3;
             }
         else if(n4 > n2 && n4 > n3 && n4 > n1)
             {
                 return n4;
             }
    }

    function avg1(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
        return ((n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4);
    }

    function min1(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
        if(n1 < n2 && n1 < n3 && n1 < n4)
            {
                return n1;
            }
         else if(n2 < n1 && n2 < n3 && n2 < n4)
             {
                 return n2;
             }
         else if(n3 < n2 && n3 < n1 && n3 < n4)
             {
                 return n3;
             }
         else if(n4 < n2 && n4 < n3 && n4 < n1)
             {
                 return n4;
             }
    }


</script>
<h1>Play With Numbers</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay so first things first

```
var n1 = +prompt("Please enter the first number: ");
```

This one is wrong, you cannot attach methods to variables in such way, simply use `=`, besides when storing multiple values you should consider utilizing some sort of array/list. Take a look here -

```
var numbers = [];
function main() {
    alert('Enter four numbers')
    numbers.push(prompt());
    numbers.push(prompt());
    numbers.push(prompt());
    numbers.push(prompt());
}
```

Using the above you are not declaring separate variables each time but instead add to the numbers array. Note that declaring global variables is not the wisest thing to do, the above is exclusively for demonstration purposes. Next are functions that you are attempting to implement;

```
function max1(n1, n2, n3, n4) {
    if(n1 > n2 && n1 > n3 && n1 > n4) {
        return n1;
}
```

Writing code like that is very error prone. Comparing variables separately extends the code and makes it very confusing for someone else reading your code. Instead try to use some of Javascript's built in array methods - as for instance `.sort()` and `.reduce()`.

```
function getMinimum() {
    // utilizing .sort method of array object
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
    var min = numbers.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    return min[0];
}

function getMaximum() {
    var max = numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a);
    return max[0];
}

function getAverage() {
    // utilizing .reduce method of array object 
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
    var sum = numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    return sum / numbers.length;
}

function getAllFour() {
    // utilizing for .. in loop
    for (var number in numbers) {
        console.log(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: *`var n1 = +prompt("Please enter the first number: ");`
This one is wrong, you cannot attach methods to variables in such way,* **Of course you can. `prompt()` returns a value and that value is what will be assigned to the variable. There's absolutely nothing wrong with that line at all.**

Comment: Also, why sort the array and return the first element, when `Math.max()` and `Math.min()` exist?